PS cmdlet piped to cmdlet . I have unsuccessfully tried to apply some of the examples
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Up' } | Select-Object Name | foreach {$_.name} 
Piped to
get-netipconfiguration | Where-Object { $_.interfacealias -eq '**piped output from cmdlet**' }
I tried unsuccessfully to apply some of the methods in previous case solutions.

You need to use $_, with the underscore, not just $.
Note: $_ is just an alias of $PSItem so you can use it instead if you prefer(it can make the code more readable).
Minor note: when using Where-Object to execute one simple comparison(like in your example) try avoiding using the scriptblock, use -Property NameOfTheProperty instead.
In your example it would be Where-Object -Property Status -eq 'Up'
There is no sensible difference in small-scale stuff, but it's a good habit to get

When it's not formatted as code, the underline doesn't appear.

You can pipe the output from Get-NetAdapter directly into Get-NetIPConfiguration, so this will work:
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Up' } | Get-NetIPConfiguration


It may be a little hard to tell from the docs, but you have to see which parameter can be piped into get-netipconfiguration, and byvalue or byname.  -Interfaceindex can be piped to Get-netipconfiguration byname (among other parameters).  Or use trial and error.  The select interfaceindex is optional, for demo purposes.
Get-NetAdapter | select interfaceindex | get-netipconfiguration
Get-NetAdapter | get-netipconfiguration

-Interfacealias works too, which is close to what you were trying:
Get-NetAdapter | select interfacealias | Get-NetIPConfiguration

Otherwise, the error message is pretty clear:
Get-NetAdapter | % name | Get-NetIPConfiguration

Get-NetIPConfiguration : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for
the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input
and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take
pipeline input.

